# should I use std::any for std::shared_ptr<void>?

Tags: c++, casting, c++17, any

I have several `producers` and one `consumer` which hold a `queue`, when producer produce an object, it wrap it into a `shared_ptr` and send to consumer queue for processing, because different producer may produce different type of object, so the queue is defined as

```
struct FrameHeader {
    int data_type;
};

class Frame {
private:
    std::shared_ptr<FrameHeader> header;
    std::shared_ptr<void> body;
public:
    Frame(const std::shared_ptr<FrameHeader> header, const std::shared_ptr<void> body);
    std::shared_ptr<FrameHeader> get_header();
    std::shared_ptr<void> get_body();
};

std::deque<std::shared_ptr<Frame>> data_q;
```

when I pop an `Frame` from `data_q`, I look into to `data_type` field in `header` to decide which object I should cast the `body` into

May question is with `c++17` I learnt there is a new feature called `std::any` that I can use to hold any object, should I use `any` in place of `shared_ptr<void>` like this?

```
    class Frame {
    private:
        std::shared_ptr<FrameHeader> header;
        any body;
    public:
        Frame(const std::shared_ptr<FrameHeader> header, const std::shared_ptr<void> body);
        std::shared_ptr<FrameHeader> get_header();
        any get_body();
    };

...
auto real_obj_ptr = any_cast<shared_ptr<RealClass>>(frame.get_body());
```

Also if there is better way of handling this situation?

Comment: Shared pointer is needed for ownership: it would delete the object whenever the last ptr is destroyed. std::any is used to hold anythin, but has no ownership. Do you need the ownership? Next, have you thought of std::variant?

Comment: @DmitryKuzminov I have many different object, variant seems to be infeasible? Maybe i am not being clear, what I mean is using any to replace void, but any is still having shared_ptr stored.

Comment: `std::variant` has a benefit of storing the objects inplace, while `std::any` allocates on heap.

Answer (score 3):

The `std::any` doesn't substitute the `std::shared_ptr` and vice versa: they have different purposes.

Shared pointer is used whenever you need to keep track over the life time of the object, and delete it when the last reference is destroyed. That is obvious. The `std::any` doesn't do that. On the other hand `std::any` can keep the reference to any object and is safer than any tricks with `void*` (`stared_ptr<void>` is one of them). Technically you may combine both:

```cpp
std::any a = std::make_shared<int>(42);
std::cout << *std::any_cast<std::shared_ptr<int>>(a);
```

This approach has a drawback that `std::any` allocates the objects on heap, because it cannot know in advance the maximum size of the type being stored. If you can limit the number of stored types, you may use a more efficient and safer pattern: `std::variant`.

Actually there are plenty of patterns that can be used, and they have their own pros and cons. For example, you may use a common base class together with `std::shared_ptr<Base>`. You may use double dispatching for safer type erasure. Nobody knows your task except of you, so try to give a detailed description of the problems you experience.

Comment: Also copying/moving a `std::any` copies/moves the underlying object, while `std::shared_ptr` doesn't. Basically, `std::any` represents a *value* of unknown type, and `std::shared_ptr<void>` is a *pointer to a value* of unknown type (though both are (often) implemented as pointers). Which one is right *really* depends on the context. For this reason, I'd also suggest `std::shared_ptr<std::any>` over `std::shared_ptr` in `std::any`. "Pointer to object of unknown, queryable type" is "better" than "object of unknown type that I hope is a pointer and whose pointed-to type I can't check as easily".